# how to convert visual hebrew to logical hebrew using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out how to convert visual hebrew to logical hebrew with vanilla JavaScript by just making a function that reverses the string given to it and then just replacing the brackets with the correct ones
e.g. `(` to `)` or `)` to `(`.

Here is an explanation for whats the difference between the two:
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-visual-vs-logical

When you reverse a string, the brackets stay the same, so for example when you have :) שלום the reversed string will be םולש :( and thats why i added the switch case

Whats going wrong is Hebrew combined with English, im using this function to print hebrew correctly in minecraft education (what it does is - it prints hebrew flipped so that the string starts from the end and ends at the start) and as you can see in the image in this link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0nkJ.jpg , the first line is supposed to be the correct one, but the second one is the one being printed

Is there a chance it can be done with regex?

```
function myHebrewPrint(text: string ): void {
   
    let reversed=""
    for(let char of text)
    {
    
        switch(char)
        {
            case "(":
                char = ")";
                break;
            
            case ")":
                char = "(";
                break;

            case "[":
                char = "]";
            
            case "]":
                char = "[";
                break;
            
            case "{":
                char = "}";
                break;
            
            case "}":
                char = "{";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        reversed=char+reversed
    }
    console.log(reversed)
}
```

Comment: Well as a none hebrew speaker what exactly is *visual hebrew to logical hebrew*? and what does this have to do with brackets?

Comment: What output do you expect to see, and what do you currently get - i.e. what's currently going wrong?

Comment: Here is a brief explanation to what's the difference
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-visual-vs-logical

Comment: @Liam when you reverse a string, the brackets stay the same, so for example when you have  :) שלום the reversed string will be םולש :(

Comment: Ok, you should add that to the question

Comment: @MikeBrockington whats going wrong is Hebrew combined with English, im using this function to print hebrew correctly in minecraft education (what it does is - it prints hebrew flipped so that the string starts from the end and ends at the start) and as you can see in the image in this link - https://imgur.com/a/zEwHCmA , the first line is supposed to be the correct one, but the second one is the one being printed

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm leaving this in case someone wants to have an attempt at this.

If I understood the requirements correctly, I think I managed to have this working. I have some explanation as comments.

```js
function visualToLogicalHebrew(text) {
    const hasHebrew = new RegExp("^[\u0590-\u05FF]+$"); //pattern to check if word has hebrew letters
    const arr = text.split(' '); //split the whole text by space, having an array full of words
    let sentence = "";

    for (const word of arr) {
        let isHebrew = hasHebrew.test(word);

        if (isHebrew) {
            sentence = word.split("").reverse().join("") + " " + sentence; //if hebrew then reverse all letters, add space and the previous sentence
        }
        else {
            sentence = sentence + word + " ";
        }
    }
    
    return sentence;
}

let result = visualToLogicalHebrew(":) שלום :subnetשלום");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it reverses the English words and the numbers as well, which im trying to avoid, thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Hmm, but in the original example in W3C that what it is supposed to do. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is narrowed down to when a word has both hebrew and english characters. What should happen then? Not reverse?

Comment: The original example in W3C didnt have any numbers or words in english with an hebrew letter before them

Comment: Could you check again? I changed some code, its my last attempt haha

Comment: still doesnt work, for some reason it doesnt reverse the word "הכתובת"

Answer (score 0):

Attaches my solution based on @Costa solution and adaptation to the complex needs in my case

1. The first regex pattern matches the Hebrew / Arabic characters and the next character (except for a new line) and repeat to export entire verses
2. The function inside the `replace` convert the string to array and `reverse` it
3. The second regular expression `test` if the extra character taken is NOT an appropriate letter like a semicolon or anything else that should not be reversed and move it back to the end by `shift` and `push`
4. The `join` convert the array back to string

```js
function reverseRTLchars(text){
  //Hebrew U+0590 to U+05FF
  //Arabic U+0600 to U+06FF
  return text.replace(/([\u0590-\u06FF]+.)+/g, function(m){
        m = m.split('').reverse();
        if(/[^\u0590-\u06FF]/.test(m[0])){
            m.push(m.shift())
        } 
        return m.join('');
    })
}


var string = `
    םלוע םולש! םויה ריואה גזמ המ?
    ש"פוסה דעו םויהמ: תיקלח ןנועמ דע ריהב
    ב םוי' 28 ץרמ 2022 (ב"פשת)
`;

document.getElementById('conten').innerHTML = reverseRTLchars(string);
```

```html
<pre id="conten" dir="rtl"></pre>
```

Comment: Sorry for answering with a huge delay, but what you did still didnt quite work, since minecraft education is quite wierd, the text will be needed to be typed backwards.
so for you to get the text i showed in my first image, you will need to write the words from left to write, instead of right to left.
starting from the 253.253 and going till the "הכתובת"
I tried to visualize the difference but every text editor shows it otherwise.

Comment: Please attach 2 relevant screenshots
1. Your input, a screenshot of the place where you write the text (as-is)
2. Your output, a screenshot of how it looks in the game